# Получить информацию о ReplyKeyboardMarkup у telegram bot используя telegram client api telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telethon

Пишу telegram клиента(именно клиента, не бота) на python telethon. Мой клиент общается с ботом, у которого есть ReplyKeyboardMarkup - это та самая клавиатура, которая всегда висит под полем ввода текста. Мне необходимо получить текст кнопок этой клавиатуры, чтобы потом общаться с ботом и понимать, на какие команды он вообще реагирует. Как получить информацию у бота о имеющейся у него ReplyKeyboardMarkup?

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, но клиент от бота в данном случае не сильно отличается. Проще будет сохранять для каждого пользователя клавиатуру и потом к ней ссылаться. На моём опыте тоже были такие задачи, и решал я их либо изменением архитектуры, либо так как описал выше.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. а в текущем виде стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос